# Drop 82 pins at a time on map

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am getting 82 addresses from the webservice and I am using forward geocoder. Now how to display all 82 addresses at a time on mapview.I put the code in for loop but its throwing the error "Too many queries has been made for this API key." Is there any way to send all the addresses and get the locations of all addresses??
This is my code in for loop...

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dictLoc = [[self.arrObjects objectAtIndex:indexValue]valueForKey:@"object_location"];

    NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@",[dictLoc valueForKey:@"object_location_number"],[dictLoc valueForKey:@"object_location_street"],[dictLoc valueForKey:@"object_location_city"],[dictLoc valueForKey:@"object_location_zip"]];

    //        if (self.forwardGeocoder == nil) {
    BSForwardGeocoder *forwardGeocoder = [[[BSForwardGeocoder alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    //        }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D southwest, northeast;
    southwest.latitude = 34.172684;
    southwest.longitude = -118.604794;
    northeast.latitude = 34.236144;
    northeast.longitude = -118.500938;
    BSForwardGeocoderCoordinateBounds *bounds = [BSForwardGeocoderCoordinateBounds boundsWithSouthWest:southwest northEast:northeast];

    // Forward geocode!
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
    [forwardGeocoder forwardGeocodeWithQuery:searchString regionBiasing:nil viewportBiasing:bounds success:^(NSArray *results) {
        [self forwardGeocodingDidSucceed:forwardGeocoder withResults:results withIndexValue:indexValue];
    } failure:^(int status, NSString *errorMessage) {
        if (status == G_GEO_NETWORK_ERROR) {
            [self forwardGeocoderConnectionDidFail:forwardGeocoder withErrorMessage:errorMessage];
        }
        else {
            [self forwardGeocodingDidFail:forwardGeocoder withErrorCode:status andErrorMessage:errorMessage];
        }
    }];
#else
    [self.forwardGeocoder forwardGeocodeWithQuery:searchString regionBiasing:nil viewportBiasing:nil];
#endif
```

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: can you show what you writing in for loop

Comment: post some code or error log :)

Comment: I have added  the code.. And the error i mentioned in the description.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put the code in for loop but its throwing the error "Too many
>   queries has been made for this API key." Is there any way to send all
>   the addresses and get the locations of all addresses??

No. This error means the API you are using is limiting the number of queries you can make. Only way to git rid of this error, and display all "82" pins for what ever reason you are trying to, is to contact the API developer and find out how to increase the number of queries you can make to the API in a given time frame. Chances are that it is a premium service and you will likely have to pay for such a thing.

Now, a better solution is to never display 82 pins on a map ever, something more like 5/10 is much more user friendly. And chances are that your API will allow something like 10 queries per minute or something similar.

An even cooler solution is building a query queue that only allows your code to call like 10 queries, then it queues up the others. Then after the allotted time, it makes another 10 queries.

Comment: I have put the delay and completed it successfully. But it is taking 12-15 secs. I want to make it less.

Comment: The delay is based on the API you are using. If you are allowed to make 82 calls in a minimum of 12-15 seconds, then that is the best you will be able to do. But if the API allows a shorter minimum time, then that is your goal obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you can do batch forward geocoding requests according to the API:

```
@interface BSForwardGeocoder : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<BSForwardGeocoderDelegate>)aDelegate;
- (void)forwardGeocodeWithQuery:(NSString *)searchQuery regionBiasing:(NSString *)regionBiasing viewportBiasing:(BSForwardGeocoderCoordinateBounds *)viewportBiasing;

#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
- (void)forwardGeocodeWithQuery:(NSString *)searchQuery regionBiasing:(NSString *)regionBiasing viewportBiasing:(BSForwardGeocoderCoordinateBounds *)viewportBiasing success:(BSForwardGeocoderSuccess)success failure:(BSForwardGeocoderFailed)failure;
#endif

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<BSForwardGeocoderDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL useHTTP;

@end
```

Also, I haven't come across an API that does batch geocoding requests, but maybe you can try a different API ([Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)?) which may give you a higher limit for requests.